# reading bytes from web site

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to create a proxy server.

I want to read the websites byte by byte so that I can display images and all other stuff. I tried readLine but I can't display images. Do you have any suggestions how I can change my code and send all data with DataOutputStream object to browser ?

```
try{
    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(req.hostname), 80);
    String file = parcala(req.url);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter socketOut = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    socketOut.print("GET "+ req.url + "\n\n");
    //socketOut.print("Host: "+req.hostname);
    socketOut.flush();
    String line;
    while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} 
catch (Exception e){}
}
```

Edited Part

This is what I should have to do. I can block banned web sites but can't allow other web sites in my program.

In the filter program, you will open a TCP socket at the specified port and wait for connections. If a
request comes (i.e. the client types a URL to access a web site), the application will process it to
decide whether access is allowed or not and then, using the same socket, it will send the reply back
to the client. After the client opened her connection to WebPolice (and her request has been checked
and is allowed), the real web page needs to be shown to the client. Therefore, since the user already gave her request, now it is WebPolice’s turn to forward the request so that the user can get the web page. Thus, WebPolice acts as a client and requests the web page. This means you need to open a connection to the web server (without closing the connection to the user), forward the request over this connection, get the reply and forward it back to the client. You will use threads to handle multiple connections (at the same time and/or at different times).

Comment: `catch (Exception e){}` lose that for a start

Comment: Please please please please do not attempt to write your own proxy server, even Apache HTTP itself suggests not using THEIR OWN proxy server unless you know what you're doing, and that code has been mature for YEARS.  An unprotected proxy server can be used by others to mask traffic.

Comment: If this isn't for a class project, I'd suggest not writing your own proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but crafting an HTTP request and reading its response incorporates somewhat more than you have done here. Readline won't work on binary data anyway.

You can take a look at the `URLConnection` class ([stolen here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)):

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```

Then you can read textual or binary data from the `in` object.

Comment: I have to do it without using URLConnection class.

Comment: I should use sockets and http requests (get,post etc...)

Comment: @AhmetTanakol **why**? As I said, creating and reading HTTP traffic is not easy. Your best guess at an HTTP request may work at one server and break at another; same goes for the response (can you handle chunks, for example?). If you want it to work under all circumstances, [read this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) and good luck. The folks behind the `URLConnection` class and its helper classes have fought all issues for you; it'd even be offensive if you refuse to use it and think you can do it better yourself.

Comment: I dont think so, so are you saying that if I use the URLConnection, can I display the whole content on my browser? Because I tried to use it and it didn't display web images. Can I use writeUTF in order to send content to browser after reading?

Comment: @AhmetTanakol I really don't know where the browser comes into play here. Please address your problems one at a time. If you can't download an image, you can never display it. Please update your question to show what you are trying to do and why it fails.

Comment: Because browser is connecting to my program with 127.0.0.1:80. I should send the content to browser via socket.

Comment: @AhmetTanakol so you're creating some sort of proxy or web server? Then sending content to your browser is part two of the problem. Part one is requesting data from another server. Fix that first.

Comment: some sort of proxy yes. I set my browser to this address and port 127.0.0.1:80. With sockets, my proxy allows or denies access to web sites. Is my get request wrong?

Comment: hooray for reinventing the wheel? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

Read line will treat the line read as a String, so unless you want to mess around with conversions over to bytes, I wouldn't recommend that.

I would just read bytes until you can't read anymore, then write them out to a file, this should allow you to grab the images, keeping file headers intact which can be important when dealing with files other than text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to grab the images, how writing the bytes to the file helps me to do that? what i want to do is after i get the contents i want to pass that information to the browser and open the page with images, texts etc...

Comment: If you're trying to display an image that exists on a different page, why are you trying to read it in through Java, why not just figure out the URL of the image and use that in an img tag?

Comment: Probably trying to scrape data off of another site, and display it with his own url.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `BufferedReader` you can try to use `InputStream`.
It has several methods for reading bytes.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html